# How can I upscale a stereo signal using PLII on a VM

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-processing, ffdshow, dolby

I want to upscale a stereo signal with PLII from an input on a VM and sent it to an output after the upscale.

I am thinking of installing Voicemeeter/Virtual Audio Cable or something like that to get an input on the VM.
I will then be able to use Dante Via on the VM host to sent the audio to the VM input and receive it again from the VM output on Dante Via then send it to my amplifier.
The solution needs to be able to initialize itself after reboot.

I have looked into different solutions the most promissing seems to be FFDShow and FFMpeg, but there is not much information about how to do this. I don't care what is used just as long as it support PLII.

I am looking for information on how to use FFDShow/FFMpeg with an application I develop or any other way to solve this.

Thanks